# DAX Calculation for Prior Period Date Range

Tags: powerbi, dax

Period Column is broken up into 2 month increments. I need to compare values vs the previous period and am not sure the DAX Formula. Below is what I have in PBI and then what I am looking to create. After this I need to show the Variance. (period is based of a Date Column)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGLBy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKYwc.png)

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296271/how-to-create-table-in-stack-overflow-answers-questions) and not through pictures

Answer (score 0):

Because your periods are not unique, we need to generate a unique identifier in order to find the previous period.  Create this calculated column:

```
PERIOD_ID:=RANKX(ALL(Table1),Table1[Year]&Table1[Period],,ASC)
```

Then we can reference that period ID to pull the previous period values, or none if it is the first period.

```
PREV_PERIOD_ACHIEVED:=var curPeriod = Table1[PERIOD_ID]

RETURN

IF(curPeriod = 1,0,CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Achieved]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[PERIOD_ID]=curPeriod-1)))
```

[image]